# What does Apple's "migration assistant" migrate?

Tags: macos, data-migration

I'm about to take ownership of a new macbook book pro, replacing one from 2008. During that time I've upgraded the OS, compiled, installed another otherwise messed with many system configurations, paths to configurations and interpreter binaries, etc. etc. So many tweaks and twists that I no longer know what is standard anymore.

In short, it is a mess, and I thought I start with a clean base. Does anyone know if Apple's "Migration Assistant" *only* migrates "higher level" applications/data and settings, or is it literally a cloning tool-- in which case I have my own disk image thankyouverymuch.

Such a simple question, but Google is not really helping me on this one.

... of course I will have my own answer in a 14 days time, but if someone else knows already, I'd much appreciate hearing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will actually have a fair amount of control over what is migrated if you choose to.

For example:

[image: Migration Assistant Screenshot]

It is not, however, a cloning tool.  It will not move "Apple" applications for instance.